# Neo4j tries to delete previously deleted relation

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I have a Neo4j Cypher query that removes a relation with label :A, and replaces it with another :A relation to a different node.

```
MATCH (n:Item), (m)
WHERE ID(n) = {nodeId} AND ID(m) = {relatedNodeId}
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r:A]->()
DELETE r
CREATE (n)-[:A]->(m)
```

When I directly load the editor page of my application that I'm developing, it loads the Item and the relation, and displays it.

```
MATCH (n)-[a:A]->(info) WHERE ID(n) = {id} RETURN a, info
```

Then, when I try to save changes (and thus run the delete+create query), it does exactly what I expected it to do.

But, if I go back to the overview page of my application (a single page app) and then go back to the editor page for the same Item and try to save it again, it throws an error:

```
neo4j.ClientError: [Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound] Unable to load RELATIONSHIP with id 274.]
```

I can't help but think that this is an issue with my client application. It only happens when I go to the edit page for a second time - the first time around I can save and re-save as often as I like, but the second time it always throws the error that it can't find the relationship with an ID one lower than the ID of the current :A relationship in the database.

I checked both in the server and in the client application, and the `{id}` and `{relId}` values are the same every time. They're numbers, in my current test case `{nodeId}` is always `7` and `{relatedNodeId}` is either `5` or `8` (switching between the two).

I fail to see why Neo4j is looking for a specific Relationship ID with the query I posted, and why it would work fine the first time around but not the second time. I'm thinking it might be some hidden caching (because every time the editor loads, it retrieves all the node and relation data again, so by the time the editor loads the second time the server has run the same loading queries 3 times) but I'm pretty new to Neo4j so it might just be a newbie mistake in my query.

Anyone who can shed some light on this issue?

I'm using Neo4j version 3.0.0, through the [neo4j](https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j) module in Node.js

Comment: The delete and create statement looks fine (personally I prefer to use a with between delete and create), as you have pointed out, its probably a the query parameters being cached somewhere. Is there a possibility for you to expose an REST api using nodejs for this particular query and use postman to call and test it? You should then have a better chance of pinpointing where the problem is.

Comment: The parameters aren't being cached in my app (neither the server nor the client). The server is just a REST API, I log and track every step of the way so I know the values are fine. I even log the full query and parameters right before they are sent to Neo4j, and everything looks correct. I thought it might perhaps be related to Neo4j internal caching of some sort. Anyhow, I tried testing it with Postman, and it doesn't throw an error, even if I run all the queries quickly a bunch of times. I'm at a loss, I have no idea what could cause the error so I have no place to start looking in my code.

Comment: If postman consistently returns the correct reply, it would seem your REST API and db seem to be working as intended and is likely not the cause of the problem. I am not sure how your client is set up and would not be able to help without knowing more about your setup.

My suggestion would be to look if you have some kind of caching setup like varnish or memcached or even redis. This may be sending cached requests to the server.

Comment: @Anomaly211 this is not the case. The request from the client is simply a `jQuery.ajax` request. I also log the received values on the server and they are always correct as expected - so the data sent from the client is correct, and it is the exact same data I tested with in Postman. I'm mostly confused about the fact that the Neo4j error seems to say that it's looking for a specific relationship ID, while I don't look for a specific ID in my query.